# How to display OK results

Tags: error-handling, elm, option-type

I am playing with the Elm examples, and I noticed the [field](http://elm-lang.org/examples/field) example gives `Result` types.  After getting stuck, I came up with this simplified case:

```
import Html exposing (text)
import String

f: Int -> Int
f x = x + 1

g: Result String Int -> Result String Int
g x = (Result.map f) x

main =
  text (  toString ( g  (String.toInt 5 ) ))
```

The result displays **`OK 6`** and I would rather it display just **`6`** -- I know that `toString` takes any type and returns a string representaton of it.  So maybe I can modify `toString`

- if result is `OK` then I can print the numerical result
- if the result is `Err` then I would like do some custom error message

Possibly this is the reason for the [`andThen`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/1.0.0/Result#andThen) since the `+ 1` operation can fail.

```
andThen : Result e a -> (a -> Result e b) -> Result e b
andThen result callback =
    case result of
      Ok value -> callback value
      Err msg -> Err msg
```

The definition of **`andThen`** is exactly what it does... and is an instance of [`case`](http://elm-lang.org/docs/syntax#conditionals).

Either with `andThen` or plain old `case` how do I fix my example?  Even if I fix it myself, it might not be the most Elm-like solution with good error handling.  So I am posting the question.

Answer (score 4):

When a function returns a Result, you have a choice - you can also return a Result, in which case you can return Err(something) or Ok(something).  This percolates your errors up to the calling function, which can decide what to do.  The other way is you can return something that isn't a result, like a String or Html.  If you go this second route, then you need to handle both possibilities of the Result and **still** return your String or Html.

So for example this function takes a result and returns a string.  It handles both possibilities, returning a string even if the result was an Err.

```
foo: Result String Err -> String
foo myres = 
  case myres of 
    Ok(str) -> str
    Err(e) -> "there was an error! uh oh"
```

Its kind of a question of how far up the hierarchy you want to go with your Result.  Do you want the errors to percolate all the way up to the top level?  Maybe your top level function is like this:

```
View: Model -> Html
View model = 
  case makeMyHtml(model) of 
    Ok(htm) -> htm
    Err(e) -> renderSpecialErrorHtmlPage(e)
```

At any rate, to get rid of the 'Ok' in this case you can do this:

```
main =
  let res = g  (String.toInt 5 ) 
  text (  toString ( Result.withDefault "g returned an error!" res))
```

If g returns Ok(6) then you get "6", but if it returns error you get "g returned an error!".